# No disjoint partition for $\{2^1, 2^2, ...,2^{15}\}$ such the sum of elements in all partitions is the same

Tags: elementary-set-theory, arithmetic

Given the set $M=\{2^1, 2^2, ...,2^{15}\}$ . Prove that there are no 3 disjoint sets $X, Y, Z$ such $M=X \cup Y \cup Z$  $S(X)=S(Y)=S(Z)$ where $S(W)$ is define as the sum of elements in the set $W$.
I need a very, very elemetary proof, such it can be explained to a fifth grader.

Answer (score 2):

Since $2^{1} + 2^{2} + \cdots + 2^{14} = 2^{15} - 2$, whichever set contains $2^{15}$ will have a larger sum than any of the others.

Comment: Proofs of $2^0+2^1+2^2+ \cdots + 2^n=2^{n+1}-1$ can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1990137/the-idea-behind-the-sum-of-powers-of-2) (binary) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22599/how-to-prove-a-formula-for-the-sum-of-powers-of-2-by-induction) (induction)

Comment: Awesome Alex . Thank you. The only proof I've seen was impling serious algebra. Thanks alot.